# Mysql how to return a test on children in one-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, database, left-join, one-to-many

I have a database consisting of two tables:

```
categories
products
```

The is a one-to-many relationship between these two table, so that every product can be linked to one and only one category with the column "category_id".

The product category has a column called "status".

**Here is my problem**:
I would like to return all categories and append two columns to the results table.

1) The first column will count the number of products in the category. (solved)

2) The second column will count the number of product where products.'status'="on sale".

My code so far (doesn't work!):

```
SELECT a.*, COUNT(b.`category_id`) AS product_count, COUNT(c.`category_id`) AS status_count
FROM `categories` AS a 
LEFT JOIN `products` AS b ON ( b.`category_id` = a.`id` )
LEFT JOIN `products` AS c ON ( c.`status` = 'on sale' AND c.`category_id` = a.`id`)
GROUP BY a.`id`
ORDER BY  a.`name` ASC;
```

The following code returns the product count column only (works!):

```
SELECT a.*, COUNT(b.`category_id`) AS equation_count
FROM `categories` AS a 
LEFT JOIN `products` AS b ON ( b.`category_id` = a.`id` )
GROUP BY a.`id`
ORDER BY  a.`name` ASC;
```

Thanks,
Nikolaj :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to an extra `JOIN`. You can use the `CASE` expression to to get the number of products that has status = 'on sale' for each category. Something like:

```
SELECT 
  a.id,
  a.name, 
  COUNT(b.`category_id`) AS product_count, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN b.status = 'on sale' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS status_count
FROM `categories` AS a 
LEFT JOIN `products` AS b ON b.`category_id` = a.`id` 
GROUP BY a.`id`, a.name
ORDER BY  a.`name` ASC;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19367/3)

---

Since you are on MySQL, you can use `SUM(b.status = 'on sale')`. This is because of the implicit conversion of boolean to 0 and 1 in MySQL, with `IFNULL` to replace `null` with 0 for those categories that has no entries in the products table:

```
SELECT 
  a.id,
  a.name, 
  COUNT(b.`category_id`) AS product_count, 
  IFNULL(SUM(b.status = 'on sale'), 0) AS status_count
FROM `categories` AS a 
LEFT JOIN `products` AS b ON b.`category_id` = a.`id` 
 GROUP BY a.`id`, a.name
ORDER BY  a.`name` ASC;
```

[**Updated SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19367/5)